# QEMU unclear id option

Tags: qemu

What is id option. I have no idea what it is and there are no results about it.
For example from Arch Linux wiki

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nic user,id=nic0,smb=shared_dir_path disk_image
```

What is id=nic0 and where do I get it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t get it, you set it. As per [QEMU documentation](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/invocation.html#sec-005finvocation):

> `-nic [tap|bridge|user|l2tpv3|vde|netmap|vhost-user|socket][,...][,mac=macaddr][,model=mn]`
> This option is a shortcut for configuring both the on-board (default) guest NIC hardware and the host network backend in one go. […]
>
> The following two example do exactly the same, to show how -nic can be used to shorten the command line length:
>
> ```
> qemu-system-x86_64 -netdev user,id=n1,ipv6=off -device e1000,netdev=n1,mac=52:54:98:76:54:32
> qemu-system-x86_64 -nic user,ipv6=off,model=e1000,mac=52:54:98:76:54:32
> ```

From the “expanded” example you can see where the `id=` goes.

On `-netdev`, `id=` means:

> Assign symbolic name for use in monitor commands.

On `-device`, the network card is assigned a network backend by specifying its ID in the `netdev=` option.

---

So there are two answers:

- It’s used when using the QEMU Monitor
- It’s used to connect network frontend and backend

With `-nic`, specifying an ID is optional, [it will be generated for you if it’s missing](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/60ca584b8af0de525656f959991a440f8c191f12/net/net.c#L1593).